# Application on my computer with a paging memory system what kind of access priveledges does it have

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, system, paging

So learning about Systems engineering and paging systems in class these past few weeks.

My question has to do with an application running on my computer. If we were using a Paging Memory Management System, does this application have direct access to my physical memory? and if so why or why not?

My thinking is that is has to go through the logical address and then be assigned to a frame before hand but not sure if it is possible to by pass all that stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we were using a Paging Memory Management System, does this application have direct access to my physical memory? and if so why or why not?

No. Applications do not have direct access to physical memory. The whole purpose of logical address translate is to prevent applications from accessing physical memory directly.